# How to pass a variable from a link to another view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When a I click to a link, I want to pass $row->id to another view.

Here it is my link:

```
foreach($artisti as $row) {
                $artists .= '
                    <a href="{{ url(\'result/artista/\'.$row->id.\'/\') }}" class="dropdown-item">'.$row->nome.'</a>
                    ';
            }
```

Here it is my controller:

```
public function result($id)
{
    return view('result')->with('id', $id);
}
```

Here it is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/result/artista/{id}', 'LiveSearch@result')->name('artista');
```

Here it is the view I want to send the variable:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')

<h1>{{$id}}</h1>

@endsection
```

Comment: I don't know what are you doing in your code. But you can pass it in many ways `href="{{ route('artista',$row->id) }}"`. This would be simple enough.

Comment: Doesn't work. Please look at my controller I've edited the question

Comment: `dd($id);` before returning to the view ? and see what it shows.

Comment: If you mean inside the controller I did it and doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have made a dropdown like thing, when you hover over the link then what is shows in your browser bottom-left-side ? does it shows something like `result/artista/1` ?

Comment: Yeah id did a dropdown. When I hover the link it gives me:  %7B%7B%20route('artista',%20['id'%20=>%20$row->id]);%20%7D%7D

Comment: Then you have a problem in making your `href `link. These things shouldn't be included

Comment: I thought the same thing. Maybe is beacouse the <a></a> is inside a varible but phpstorm corrects everything. <a href="{{ route(\'artista\', [\'id\' => $row->id]); }}" class="dropdown-item">'.$row->nome.'</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make your link in this way. Check that and let me know

```
foreach($artisti as $row) {
            $artists .= '
                <a href="'.{{ route('artista',$row->id) }}.'" class="dropdown-item">'.$row->nome.'</a>
                ';
        }
```

> If above doesn't work then do this way

```
foreach($artisti as $row) {
            $artists .= '
                <a href="'.route('artista', ['id' => $row->id]).'" class="dropdown-item">'.$row->nome.'</a>
                ';
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. There are maybe some syntax error cause neither my dropdown works now

Comment: I don't know how you did it but it works fine. I'm sorry cause I don't have enough points to vote your answer up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try  this in your blade

`{{ url('result/artista/'.$row->id) }}`

`Route::get('/result/artista/{id}', 'LiveSearch@result')`

Edit1: For your named route only

`route('artista', ['id' => $row->id]);`

in controller : try `print_r($id)`

Comment: Doesn't work. Please look at my controller I've edited the question